# storing value in a page across postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net

What should I use to store a vlaue that is used by a number of methods of the same page ? 
It will not be used in other pages but will be used across postbacks . Do I use static
variable or session or hiddenfield or something else ?

Thanks a lot .

Comment: You posted some questions, You get some answers. Some of them is good, some is best. So, select that best answer and Accept it. By doing that, you will give some reputation points to someone, who answered question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's up to You to decide which way is best for you: viewstate, hidden field, session, database record and etc. For your question looks that best answer: viewstate.

- ViewState - simple, relatively low security (user can modify, but it's difficult if you use validation), uses network traffic
- hidden field - simple, low security (user can modify), uses network traffic
- Session - simple, high security, you must think how dispose value later (if you revisit page and don't need that value take effect)
- Database - relatively difficult, secure

Comment: Viewstate looks the best for me . But how can a user modify a viewstate or hiddenfield ? To clarify more, I am trying to count the number of clicks for some button .

Comment: No, client can't modify directly viewstate (I mean "directly" is in browser, by javascript) - only on postback. For example, user clicks button, postback, fires button click event, in code you set viewstate (ViewState["clicks"]=(int)ViewState["clicks"]++). Hidden field can be easily modified directly with javascript code, without any posts.

Answer (score 0):

### Store the value in session state:

```
int someValue = 123;
Session["SomeValue"] = someValue;
```

### To retrieve it:

```
someValue = (int)Session["SomeValue"];
```

Comment: You utilize the session state for persisting data across multiple pages.  "It will not be used in other pages .." therefore he should be utilizing the View State

Comment: Not if he wants to keep his page size down, plus it's more secure than ViewState ;-)